# Automation in python with looping

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, automation

I work with computer calculations. I share a unix machine to perform the calculations, and I use a rung09 command (configured on the machine) to perform my calculations:

```
rung09 <file name without extension>
```

This starts the calculation, and inside the directory it generates a .log file with the same name as the file I ran rung09 on, which will store the calculation data.

I have more than 1000 files and I want to run 1 at a time so as not to overload the machine.

I started by writing a script in python.

The main idea was to

1. Enter a directory
2. List the names of the files and store them in a variable (without the extension)
3. Run a loop using the rung09 command for each element in the list.

update
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
I got solve the problem guys, thank you very much

```
import os
import subprocess
import time

diretorio = "/usr/home/joao_pedro/input/calculos/"

os.chdir(diretorio)

def check_termination(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as log_file:
        content = log_file.read()
        normal_termination_count = content.count("Normal termination")
        error_termination_count = content.count("Error termination")
        
        if normal_termination_count >= 2 or error_termination_count >= 1:
            return True
        return False


# Lista todos os arquivos no diretório
nomes_arquivos = os.listdir()

# Filtra apenas os nomes de arquivos (excluindo diretórios)
arquivos = [nome.split('.')[0] for nome in nomes_arquivos if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(nome))]

files = sorted(arquivos)

for file in files:
    subprocess.run(["rung09", file])
    log_file_path = os.path.join(diretorio, f"{file}.log")
    
    time.sleep(5)

    while not check_termination(log_file_path):
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: "I have difficulties with the for and while commands." - can you show us what you attempted, and describe how it failed (or failed to match your expectations at least)

Comment: I can't create a loop that when I use the rung09 command and the element in the list, the loop respects the condition I've given it, which is to read the .log file associated with the current process and find if there is "normal termination" or "error termination", the looping basically goes on and on putting all the calculations in at once.

Comment: Please post your code rather than descriptions of your code :) [update your existing post with the code that doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76921947/edit)

Comment: for file in files:
      subprocess.run(["rung09", file]) #Theoretically, here you will go through each element of the list and put rung09 file_name_without_extension

      (In this part I need to put a loop or a condition that makes the outer loop respect these conditions before repeating for each element in the list)

Comment: Comments are not formatted well. [edit] the question instead.

Comment: @JonSG Do you suggest that I apply this method inside my loop?

Comment: Perhaps you want `subprocess.Popen("rung09", file, cwd=diretorio)`?

Comment: Sorry, I see that you are already using `subprocess.run()`. That call is blocking and the second will only start after the first is complete. Is that not what you see? Is `run09` actually starting something itself in the background and returning immediately?

Comment: The looping starts rung09 for the first element of the list, and soon after it starts for the second element of the list, I tried to put a criterion to be obeyed before it starts for the next one, but it ignores it or the logic must be wrong @JonSG

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen What is the difference between subprocess.popen and subprocess.run?

Comment: `Popen` runs the subprocess in parallel with your Python script, and you need to take care of various low-level tasks yourself to manage the subprocess. Unless you are specifically looking for parallel execution, probably stick to `subprocess.run`, as also recommended in the documentation. It should behave exactly like you say you want things to be. If `run09` does something in the background and then returns while work continues, that's out of Python's control, and ours, with the details you have provided so far.

Comment: @feyn.py The suggestion to use `Popen` was in order to give you control over the working directory of the child process - you're only passing the name of the file to the target program, not the full path

Comment: guys thanks very much, i got solve the problem.

I put the script in principal text. Thanks very much guys

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import subprocess
import time

diretorio = "/usr/home/joao_pedro/input/calculos/"

os.chdir(diretorio)

def check_termination(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as log_file:
        content = log_file.read()
        normal_termination_count = content.count("Normal termination")
        error_termination_count = content.count("Error termination")
        
        if normal_termination_count >= 2 or error_termination_count >= 1:
            return True
        return False


# Lista todos os arquivos no diretório
nomes_arquivos = os.listdir()

# Filtra apenas os nomes de arquivos (excluindo diretórios)
arquivos = [nome.split('.')[0] for nome in nomes_arquivos if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(nome))]

files = sorted(arquivos)

for file in files:
    subprocess.run(["rung09", file])
    log_file_path = os.path.join(diretorio, f"{file}.log")
    
    time.sleep(5)

    while not check_termination(log_file_path):
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).